# jQuery XML Parsing IE7 / IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to access XML content attached to the end of a HTML document (generated stuff) with jquery using this method:

```
$("SELECTION_STATE").find("CHARACTERISTIC").each( function() {
     if($(this).attr("name") == "Z_MDST" ) {
         alert($(this).find("MEMBER").attr("name"));
     }
 });
```

this works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE, it won't alert anything.

this is the xml I'm trying to traverse

```
<SELECTION_STATE>

    <SELECTION type="CARTESIAN_PRODUCT">
      <CHARACTERISTICS>
        <CHARACTERISTIC name="Z_MDST">
          <SELECTIONS>
            <SELECTION type="SINGLE_MEMBER">
              <MEMBER name="00002213" type="MEMBER" text="2213"/>
            </SELECTION>
          </SELECTIONS>
        </CHARACTERISTIC>
```

is there any way I can achieve that with jquery 1.5?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are in a HTML document. IE won't recognize XML.

```
console.log($("SELECTION_STATE").get());
```

returns **object HTMLUnknownElement** in IE

In order to use the XML you'll have to run it through the IE XML parser. Something like.

```
var x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
x.loadXML(yourXML)
```

You'll obviously only want to do this *if($.browser.msie)*

Side question: Are you loading the XML with AJAX?

Updated: Full Example

```
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
var myXML = document.body.innerHTML;  // or wherever you are storing the XML in the DOM
xmlDoc.loadXML(myXML)

if (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) {
   var myErr = xmlDoc.parseError;
   console.log("You have error " + myErr.reason);
} else {
   console.log(xmlDoc.xml);
}

$("SELECTION_STATE", xmlDoc).find("CHARACTERISTIC").each( function() {
     if($(this).attr("name") == "Z_MDST" ) {
         alert($(this).find("MEMBER").attr("name"));
     }
});
```

Comment: thanks.
no, this is a special case where I need to access generated HTML content in the same document (closed source commercial product) with a few lines of javascript. no AJAX involved :-(

I'll try your suggestion

Comment: related question - how would I manage to load the current document?

Comment: It's important to notice the XML must validate, or IE won't parse it (it's not as forgiving as HTML..) You're first example missed some closing tags

Answer (score 6):

Since you are already using jQuery use the parseXML function(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/ added in version 1.5)

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);

$(xmlDoc).find("CHARACTERISTIC").each( function() {
    if($(this).attr("name") == "Z_MDST" ) {
        alert($(this).find("MEMBER").attr("name"));
    }
});
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, i am using jquery 1.7 and testing ie8 on win7

Comment: It's important to remember here that with IE, you can't use `.html()` to get a node's contents. You have to use `.text()`